# Multiple datasources with Grails 3.1.5 and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, grails, multiple-databases

I am trying to connect to two postgresql databases from a single Grails 3.1.5 application, my application.yml looks like this:

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        username: username
        password: password
        dialect: net.kaleidos.hibernate.PostgresqlExtensionsDialect
    dataSource_two:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        username: username
        password: password
        dialect: net.kaleidos.hibernate.PostgresqlExtensionsDialect
environments:
    development:
        dataSources:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbone
            dataSource_two:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbtwo
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

I am getting this error and cannot start the application

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager_dataSource_two' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager_dataSource_two': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory_dataSource_two' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory_dataSource_two': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75)
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Looks like grails cannot find hibernate.cache.region.factory_class but as you can see I have that property in application.yml. I also checked if the class exists in classpath and it does. Any ideas why I am getting this error ?

Comment: just to be sure, which hibernate version you are using? Hibernate 4?

Answer (score 1):

the hibernate settings are datasource-specific, too.

so try adding a `hibernate_two` block with the hibernate settings for your `dataSource_two`

Comment: Nope, did not work, I added hibernate_two block right after the first hibernate block. I even tried to add hibernate settings under datasources.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the grails version to 3.1.9 and used the same exact configuration and it worked. The only thing I changed is was 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' to 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory'.